# VB.NET - Can't I "disable" the Startup form when it open a new form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, showdialog

I have learn today that using the method .ShowDialog() to open a new form, it will not allow to user (until the new form be closed) to "use" this form but I tried do it and this form still can be "usable".

The form that open the new one is my startup object. What did I do wrong?

- Start-up object: Form
- Form to be open: AddQuestion

---

At Form I have:

```
Private Sub ButtonX5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonX5.Click
        AddQuestion.ShowDialog(Me)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Show code how you initialize your AddQuestion form. And what you mean in _use this form_ `Form` or `AddQuestion`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim aqForm = New AddQuestion()
aqForm.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example we have Form1 and we want to call Form2. 
we may write like this in Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object s, EventArgs e) 
{ 
Form2 f=new Form2(); 
f.Show(); 

}
```

we can also write `f.ShowDialog();`

**The difference:**

Show method does not make the target form (Form2 in this case) as a modal dialog 
box. `ShowDialog()` will make `Form2()` as a modal dialog box. So, when we use 
`ShowDialog()` method, we cannot click anywhere on Form1 unless we close the 
instance of Form2. In case of `Show()`, we can click on Form1 even when Form2 is open.